# uint8_t array within another uint8_t array possible?

Tags: objective-c, c, pointers

I'm trying to figure out how I can have the two byte `appSignatureBytes` array within `commentExtension`'s array so the code can be kept seperate; would there be a way of doing this? `appSignatureBytes[0-sizeof(appSignatureBytes)]` so that all elements are inserted at compile time?

```
const uint8_t appSignatureBytes [] = { 0x48, 0x69 };

const uint8_t commentBytesSizeByte = sizeof(appSignatureBytes);

const uint8_t commentExtension [] = { extensionIntroducerByte,
commentLabelByte, commentBytesSizeByte, appSignatureBytes[0-sizeof(appSignatureBytes)], 
blockTerminatorByte };
```

Comment: @RSahu what is an alternative in C?

Comment: I was wrong about it being not possible in C. The answer by @CarlNorum shows how to do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really need it at compile time, you can use a shared preprocessor definition:

```
#define MAGIC_BYTES 0x48, 0x69
const uint8_t appSignatureBytes[] = { MAGIC_BYTES };

const uint8_t commentBytesSizeByte = sizeof appSignatureBytes;

const uint8_t commentExtension[] =
{
    extensionIntroducerByte,
    commentLabelByte,
    commentBytesSizeByte,
    MAGIC_BYTES, 
    blockTerminatorByte
};
```